# Why do I get YUI Parse Error with sencha app build?

Tags: extjs, yui, sencha-cmd

I've just started using Sencha Cmd, but the first time I ran sencha app build I get errors like this:

YUI Parse Error (invalid property id => (Ext.cmd.derive('atlas.wizard.base.store.WizardStore'

Parse Error (missing name after . operator =>     var aggExport = wizardData.export;) -- unknown-file:74618:38

Is YUI strict or something regarding what you can do in your code?

Answer (score 2):

Its because we are using JavaScript keyword "export". So sencha cmd will help us stop doing this.